# How to print debug statments in Giraph

Tags: cloudera, giraph

I find the below statement before print log statement. 
`if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())`
How can we enable or disable debug statements when running a Giraph program?
And where can one find the logs of these statements?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To access the logs try something like

```
yarn logs --applicationId application_1399469361545_0003
```

where you can find the application ID in the console output.

Comment: Is there any configuration parameter through which I can enable or disable them ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, i don't understand why the author choose this as accepted answer...

Answer (score 2):

Setting the custom argument

-ca
giraph.logLevel=debug

Should do the work